# VB.net Prining Custom PaperSize

Tags: vb.net, printing

i have been researching this a lot. I have tried several ways to handle this but for some reason the printer is ignoring the papersize specified. This last iteration of code seems like it should work however it does not and print papersize much larger(700 pixels length and 200 width)

```
 Private _pdPrint As PrintDocument
 Private _PaperSize As Printing.PaperSize


Public Sub DoPrinting()
    Try
        ' Start the print.
        _PaperSize = New PaperSize()
        _PaperSize.RawKind = Printing.PaperKind.Custom
        _PaperSize.Width = 300
        _PaperSize.Height = 200
        _PaperSize.PaperName = "Letter"

        _pdPrint.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = _PaperSize
        _pdPrint.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = _PaperSize



        _pdPrint.Print()
        If _exceptionFlag = True Then
            Throw New Exception
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. You don't want to change _default_ sizes. You want to change the size for this specific job. I don't remember where the option is, but if has "default" in the name it's not right. Look around; you'll find it.It might be the event args for the print event.

Comment: 2. Don't use the name "Letter", as that will conflict with a stock size and may prevent saving the size.

Comment: 3. Don't just `Throw` in a Catch if you don't do anything else there. You can remove the Try/Catch statement and leave the body behind by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Add the event PrintPageEventArgs

```
Private Sub PD_PrintPage_DrawImage(e As PrintPageEventArgs)
```

Add your code there

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried various ways... and I found this and it allows me to print A6 paper size... before that, although I had set the A6 paper size, but it still print A6 size in A4 paper size.. here is little addition, in PrintButton... at ***PrinterSetting.Defaultpagesetting***

```
PrintDialog1.ShowDialog()
        PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = New Printing.PaperSize("A6", 410, 580)
        PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0
        PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0
        PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 0
        PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0
        PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings
```

(google translation...)